# Browser code and beautifulsoup collection different

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to parse soccerstand front page soccer matches and fail because the items I get with BeautifulSoup are really different from what I see in browser.
My code is simple at the moment:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://soccerstand.com/') as response:
    url_data = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url_data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('div.event__match'))
```

So I tried this and this failed. When I checked soup variable it turned out not to contain such divs at all, so what I get with BS is different from what I see by inspecting code on the website.

What's the reason for that? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Most likely some elements are loaded dinamically via JS queries. You would need to manually send said queries with requests, or better do your scraping with selenium.

Comment: Selenium is something I still have to learn. Thanks for your suggestion, makes much sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: I believe yes currently